# Body jumping x pixels left, when a scrollbar is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

When you have Angular routing, this problem becomes extremely aware and annoying. When one of the pages has a scrollbar and the second doesn't, switching between those, you'll notice the body shifting from right to left and vise versa for the width of scrollbar.

Is there any elegant fix for this? I've thought of adding a padding/margin to the right side of page (width of scrollbar) when a scrollbar doesn't exist in the current route/view to simulate having a scrollbar and removing this shift. You could calculate the width of scrollbar by subtracting inner width from outer width of document and then adding the result as a padding/margin, but that doesn't seem like a perfect fix for me.

Is there a better and perhaps more elegant or simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put in CSS to always show the scrollbar (even when there is not enough content to warrant one)

From https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/force-vertical-scrollbar/

```
html {
       overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force the vertical scrollbar to show by setting `overflow-y: scroll`

```css
div {
  overflow-y: scroll;

  /* Additional styling for the demo */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this is a handy solution indeed, but is there an alternative to what I have suggested without forcing the scrollbar, when there actually is no need for it, perhaps?

Comment: There may be, but that may be very tricky to get to work properly, since not all devices / browsers handle scrollbars the same way... (Different widths, for example)